# Direct user via incoming link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to use an if statement to change the styling of a page, if a user comes from a specific link and do not know how I should set this up.

For example, if a user comes from a bitly link I would like for them to see different styling than if a user comes from any other link.

I am developing in Wordpress, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query strings, send different users to different urls.  `www.yourwebsite.com?src=bitly`

```
if(isset($_GET) AND $_GET['src']=='bitly'){

//special styling or actions for those coming from bitly

}
```

So you should create links from different websites that link to the same page, but with a different query string, so for example a link from your blog: `yourwebsite.com?src=your_blog`.  This should work with bitly, enter the complete url including the query string into bitly.

Comment: I don't see that this is working. Are you thinking that I would put a redirect in the if statement?

Comment: You should create a bitly link that links to www.yourwebsite.com?src=bitly

Comment: One thing we are trying to avoid is redirecting the user or using a new link. We want to use the same link but for the users coming from bitly the page will have different elements and styling. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: It might be possible but it's a lot of extra work and might be difficult to execute.  I'm not sure what the hesitation to using a query string is? Look at any url (for example the one above) and you'll notice it has a query string.  Another option would be to use query string, store src value in sessions, redirect user to your main site (no query string), and display data to them based on session vars.  Seems like a lot of extra work for something that most people probably wont notice.

Comment: I agree, I suppose we could go with a query string and see how it works out. I am still a bit confused about the if statement. When I incorporate it, it breaks the site. I know there is something I am missing.

Comment: Sorry I realized there was a typo and I just fixed it.  Use isset($_GET) instead of isset($_GET[])

Comment: That solved it, i'll give anymore input if I come up with other thoughts. Thanks!